# How to pass double[][] into a method call?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi I am trying to init an object with a double value in the format double filter[3][3];
but i keep getting the following error.

cannot convert 'double[3][3]' to 'double' in assignment.

in my header i have this

```
@interface filter : NSObject
{
    double **matrix;
}
@property(nonatomic)double **matrix;
-(id)initWithMatrix:(double**)filterMatrix;
```

inside my class i have this method.

```
-(id)initWithMatrix:(double**)filterMatrix
{
    matrix = filterMatrix;
    return self;
}
```

and i am trying to call it like this.

```
double filter[3][3] = {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0};
MyMatrix *myMatrix = [[MyMatrix alloc] initWithMatrix:filter];
```

I now get the error.

```
Error: Cannot convert double[*][3] to double** in argument passing
```

Any help on this issue would be amazing.
Thanks
A

Comment: You are trying to pass it a matrix of doubles but the method is expecting a single double.  Thats why you have that error.

Comment: This is different, I tried  updating the previous post as it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A two-dimensional array is not the same thing as a pointer-to-a-pointer.  You have two choices - change the `filter` class to contain a 2D array, or change your initialization to use pointer-to-pointers.

In choice #1, you're could keep a copy of the array in your `filter` instance, instead of just holding a pointer.  You need to change the class interface:

```
@interface filter : NSObject
{
    double matrix[3][3];
}

-(id)initWithMatrix:(double[3][3])filterMatrix;
```

Then your implementation of `initWithMatrix:` can just do a `memcpy()` or the equivalent to copy the data into your instance.

Choice #2 is a bit different.  Keep your other code the way it is, but change your initialization of `filter`:

```
double row0[3] = {0,0,0};
double row1[3] = {0,1,0};
double row2[3] = {0,0,0};
double **filter[3] = { row0, row1, row2 };
```

It's probably safer to `malloc()` all of those arrays, since otherwise you're going to end up with references to stack variables in your `filter` class, but I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `double**` isn't the equivalent of `double[*][*]`. In fact, `double[*][*]` is an invalid type, because it leaves the stride undefined. `double**` is a pointer to a pointer to a double, or to put it another way, it's a pointer to an array of doubles. You should just use `double*` as your type.

*Edit*: To clarify, `double[*][3]` is still just an array of doubles, even though it has 2 dimensions. This is still the equivalent of `double*`.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing as a parameter a double 2d array(double[][]) when your method signature asks for a double (a primitive like 34.2). 
set the method declaration to

`- (id)initWithMatrix:(double*) matrix;`

this passes a pointer to your array (2d) to the method.
edit: missed a semicolon.