# how to pass a double with [n][n] values into a method

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass double[][] into a method call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216800/how-to-pass-double-into-a-method-call)

Hi I am trying to init an object with a double value in the format double filter[n][n];
but i keep getting the following error.

in my header i have this

```
@interface filter : NSObject
{
    double **matrix;
}
@property(nonatomic) double **matrix;
-(id)initWithMatrix:(double**)filterMatrix;
```

inside my class i have this method.

```
-(id)initWithMatrix:(double**)filterMatrix
{
    matrix = filterMatrix;
    return self;
}
```

and i am trying to call it like this.

```
double filter[3][3] = {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0};
MyMatrix *myMatrix = [[MyMatrix alloc] initWithMatrix:filter];
```

I now get the error.

```
Error: Cannot convert double[*][3] to double** in argument passing
```

Any help on this issue would be amazing.
Thanks
A